# Just upgraded from window 8.1 to window 10 and there's no sound enhancement tab

Tags: audio, windows-10

So the volume isn't loud enough even at maximum. I went to playback devices and properties only to find that the sound enhancement tab is missing. I have conexant smartaudio hd as my default device

Comment: Is there now a Dolby tab? Or a separate control panel applet for SmartAudio, rather than the standard Windows audio device panel? It might also be helpful to know what brand & model of computer you are working with. Some of these issues are specific to that.

Comment: I am using a Toshiba Satellite P75-A. There's also doesn't seem to be a Dolby tab or a separate control panel.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have the latest drivers for your hardware, all connections are set and fixed correctly and that if you have an external volume control is set louder and not turned down.

If all that has been checked go to start menu type 'Sound'. Once there click properties and you should be able to open the master volume. and testing using the enhancements tab.

If this doesn't work have a look at configure and set the speakers up as you have them physically setup.

This should help, send some screen shots of what you get, if this doesn't sort it out.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean if the connections are set and fixed, but as for everything else, I did it all and there seems to be no change at all. I configured it and it just says everything is configured. The enhancement tab is still missing.

Comment: Connections meaning nothing loose all physically connected ok. - Also check the drivers and make sure they are the latest and are windows 10 compatible. Post model and driver numbers to have a check. To get this go to properties - and properties again

Comment: Is this what you mean?
http://imgur.com/WGHkFTU

http://imgur.com/TUkEThh

Comment: Ok try uninstalling your sound drivers. Go to your machines web site and download drivers and install drivers for Windows 8.1 and see if that helps? I know you are on Windows 10 now but this may help.

Comment: Ok so I tried doing what you said and that didn't seem to work. I was looking around and found a method and it seems to work but I just wanted to make sure if there might be any issue with it. So I went to device manager and went to sound,video, and game controllers. Update drivers, browse from list and then I selected high definition audio device. After I've done that, the enhancement tab is now where it's suppose to be.

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same problem!
I did the same as you did "So I went to device manager and went to sound,video, and game controllers. Update drivers, browse from list and then I selected **high definition audio device**."
Now the problem is solved!
Thanks for sharing a good solution!

Comment: This was already suggested nearly a year ago.

Comment: @Ramhound: But only in a comment.